# Enable to Read Emails through Google Gmail API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail, google-apps, google-authentication

Hi I want to read all the emails, I create a google app as shown below
[image]

Now I'm testing through following code.

```
public async Task ListLabels()
        {
            UserCredential credential = null; ;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret_899062187155-oog0nddbvujerg5pdklp24clt25rg9ut.apps.googleusercontent.com.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None);
            }

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Gmail Test",
            });

            try
            {
                ListLabelsResponse response = service.Users.Labels.List("me").Execute();
                foreach (Label label in response.Labels.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(label.Id + " - " + label.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Now, Once I login I got an error as

[image]

I can't figure out which redirect URL i need to set.

Answer (score -1):

While creating project select application type as Other and then Create you credential will work:

[image: see image]